# How can I lock keys inside 2007 Mazda6?

Tags: mazda, key

I am getting my car towed to a location for me to pick it up at a later time. I have a spare key and want the driver the lock the other key in the car.

Unfortunately technology is getting in my way. The boot would seem like an option, but you can't lock the car while the boot is open.

And while the car is unlocked, so is the boot.

Is there a solution I have overlooked?

Comment: Some cars will let you lock the door manually (without the key) if you hold the handle up while shutting it.

Answer (score 1):

I have circumvented this feature by opening a front and rear door, close the front door and reach thru from the back seat and manually lock the front door. Manually lock the rear door and shut it. It worked on my Ford Taurus.

Comment: This sounds like a reasonable approach.

Comment: @mikes - I have a Mazda6 and this doesn't work for me.  If I try to lock the front door while the rear door is open, it immediately unlocks.

Comment: Since that may not work try removing the key fob as that may be the culprit. If the key fob is part of the key use the valet key as it normally does not contain the remote.

Comment: Worked on my 2008 Mazda 6 as well -- THANKS, as I had to let the car run in the parking lot at work to charge my battery (water levels had been too low).